# Make certain UIButtons disappear using UISegmentedControl

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a set of `UIButtons` and a `UISegmentedControl` with 3 segments inside my storyboard.
The segments of `UISegmentedControl` should work as following;
When first is selected, show all buttons,
When second is selected, hide **Button - Button1** and **Button - Button2**,
(When third is selected, hide **Button - Button1**, **Button - Button2** and **Button - Button3**).

What should I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

1. Assign the view controller to be your segmented control's target and implement the action message. You can either do this in IB or using [`addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget%3aaction%3aforControlEvents%3a) and setting the event type to `UIControlEventValueChanged`.
2. In the value change action method hide or show the buttons you want using their [hidden](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/hidden) property.